# Android Facebook Flutter login crashes app

Tags: android, facebook, flutter

Hey so I have recently started developing an app using flutter and I have already coma across a few issues. I'll quickly resume my situation :

My app uses firebase auth and I uses the android studio refactor feature for androidX.

This managed to get me a working application with a login form but no way to fill in the login form because the android API 28 has a bug in that it does not show the keyboard after you higlight the textinput. But for fire auth you need the API level 28 ...

I managed to get around this by using the flutter channel dev.

Now so far everything works login in and registering users with the firebase auth.

Next I want to implement the facebook login and this is where I encountered even more trouble.

I used the https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login package and followed all the steps and went through the whole configuration on the firebase page and the facebook developer page.

- Add the res/strings.xml
- Add permission the manifest
- Add  and the two  under the application key in the android manifest
- Add "implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.40.0'" under the app level gradle dependencies
- Checked the jcenter() in the project level grable repositories

The actual dart code seems fine and the project builds and runs correctly on IOS

I do not get any errors even running flutter in verbose mode. The logcat is also completly empty.

I am at a complete loss it's really starting to feel like flutter is not really stable after all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:** This issue seems to be androidX related and should be fixed as soon as this pull request : 
https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/pull/87/commits/70dec4403710eb4c52a98e035a0a5e7d7f551d76

is merged.

Comment: If I remove all the code that uses the flutter_facebook_login dependency and the dependency itself from pubsspec everything works but as soon as I ad it as a dependency everything crashes again even when the library is not used anywhere in the dart code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it working by copying the repository locally and adding the changes in the aforementioned pull request.

Then in my pubspec file I used the path: key to set the dependency to my local file instead of the official git.

you can also use 
git:
  url: (url to your fork with the fixes in place)

I had to run flutter clean before rebuilding the app and now everything works.

**EDIT** A comment has just been added on the pull request thread :

> As we are not sure when this will be merged, you can adjust your `pubspec.yaml` in the meantime:

```
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_facebook_login:
    git: 
      url: https://github.com/yudaprama/flutter_facebook_login
      ref: android-x
```